# PHP setcookie for 1 Year will not work

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to set a PHP cookie to expire 1 Year from when the user logged in, and I'm doing it this way:

```
setcookie("myCookie",'exampleUserName',(365 * 24 * 60) ,'/');
```

The problem is, when I view the cookie using the console in Chrome or Firefox, it show Expires `Sun, 05, 2014` in Chrome and `Expires = Session` in Firefox.

Any other site like Google or stackoverflows cookies show the correct expiration date.

How can I set this right?

Comment: Your `365 * 24 * 60` is missing a factor of `60` and must be added to `time()`, it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Do like this...

```
setcookie("myCookie",'exampleUserName',time()+31556926 ,'/');// where 31556926 is total seconds for a year.
```

Comment: I got wrong expire date results using this code and not every year has `31556926` seconds, leap years for example.

Answer (score 52):

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, strtotime("+1 year"));
```

Comment: I have had this method for years but it has stopped working since a year back or so.

Answer (score 6):

try this one

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + ( 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

Answer (score 2):

The third param is the time in future that mean `time() + time in seconds`. Your `365 * 24 * 60` means 1971 ( 1970 + 1 ), this is in the past. Cookie in past will not be used - people set cookie to the past time to clear cookie.
Do exactly like Shankar.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
       setcookie("TestName", "Test Value", time()+3600 * 24 * 365);
?>

>> Here 'TestName' is name of cookie.
>> "Test Value" is value to store.
>> time()+3600 * 24 * 365 - will set cookie time till 1 year.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

don't complacate it

just do one thing

there are 86400 secound in a day so just multiply

here is an example of 30 days

```
setcookie("test","value",time() + (86400 * 30));
```

generaliz it like (86400 * days)

```
setcookie("test","value",time() +(86400 * 365));
```